# XSD .Net nillable attribute

Tags: .net, xsd.exe

XSD element definition is:

```
<xs:complexType name="Body">
        <xs:all>
           <xs:element name="Name" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

I am using .Net auto generated class to access the element in .Net code. Is there anyway to differentiate between non presence of the element in the xml and presence of the element with nillable="true".

i.e. between

```
<Body></Body>
```

and

```
<Body><Name xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/></Body>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) :

> use a special pattern to create a Boolean field recognized by the XmlSerializer, and to apply the XmlIgnoreAttribute to the field. The pattern is created in the form of propertyNameSpecified. For example, if there is a field named "MyFirstName" you would also create a field named "MyFirstNameSpecified" that instructs the XmlSerializer whether to generate the XML element named "MyFirstName"

See the example at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lEGeGv